# Naming mutliple xlsx files with TRUE of FALSE if character string is present in a particular sheet

Tags: r, xlsx, pdf-scraping

This code reads a xlsx file and creates individualy named files based on sheet number and a value found at a particular location (in this case temp[2,1]). However because each file and sheet is slightly different the names are inconsistant.

```
sheet_to_read <- c(11,12,13,14)
for( excelsheet in files) {
for (sheet in sheet_to_read) {
temp <- read_excel( path = excelsheet, sheet = sheet, col_names = FALSE)
write.csv( temp, file = paste0( "./", gsub("./", "", excelsheet), temp[2,1], sheet,".csv") )
}}
```

I would like is a way of naming the files with TRUE or FALSE if a specific character string is present any where within the sheet, in this case 'vivax'. So in this case:

```
GBD2016_2_915_Boletin Epidemiologico_2016_37sheet21true.xls
GBD2016_2_915_Boletin Epidemiologico_2016_37sheet22false.xls`
```

Example file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p4HAuFl7Codine1Vvb8SzA7OHTzraaHz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try `grepl("vivax", temp[2,1])` returns `TRUE/FALSE` (instead of `temp[2,1]`) if the string is present

Comment: Am I right in thinking that only checks that particular location? I want it to check all strings within each sheet.

Comment: Not clear from your question what you really wanted

Comment: Ok I have changed it.

Comment: If it is to check if there is any then `grepl("vivax", unlist(temp))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a tibble, and it is not known which column has which type,
I created this:

```
isWordInTibble <- function(word, tibble) {
  # case insensitive
  any(unlist(
    sapply(1:ncol(tibble), 
           function(i) tolower(word) %in% tolower(as.character(unlist(tibble[, i]))))))
}
```

It looks whether the word is in any of the column vectors - looks through all columns.

Replace your file argument in your `write.csv` command by:

```
file = gsub(".xls", 
            paste0(substr(temp[2, 1], 
                          1, 
                          5), # just first 5 letters
                   gsub("sheet", "", sheet), 
                   substr(tolower(as.character(isWordInTibble("vivax", tmp))),
                          1, 
                          1), # just first letter ("t" or "f") 
                   ".csv"), 
            excelsheet)
```

Then it might work!

I tried to shorten the names using `substr(, start, end)` and `gsub()`.

**Appendix**

Since you asked how to print then only the files containing the word but not those which don't contain it:

In your example, instead of the `write.csv()` command, replace it with:

```
if (isWordInTibble("vivax", tmP)) {
  write.csv(temp, 
            file = gsub(".xls", 
                        paste0(substr(temp[2, 1], 
                                      1, 
                                      5), # just first 5 letters
                               gsub("sheet", "", sheet), 
                               substr(tolower(as.character(isWordInTibble("vivax", temp))),
                                      1, 
                                      1), # just first letter ("t" or "f") 
                               ".csv"), 
                        excelsheet))
}
```

Then it prints out only if the `isWordInTibble` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: I will do some testing with more files but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks! It looks more complex than the other solution - but it is because I wanted to catch the cases where the word is in a column typed as `factor`.

Comment: The only problem I have with it, is it tries to save really really long file names, is there a way to limit this but still keep the sheet number and true or false?

Comment: you can replace things and shorten things by `gsub()` since it can do regex. What you want to shorten? - can you give some examples?

Comment: If you want to limit `tmp[2, 1]` to let's say 10 characters, you could do: `substr(temp[2, 1], 1, 10)`

Comment: How about the version now?

Comment: Sometime temp[2,1] is a really long string so when it tries to save it as a file name it has an error, I guess becuase there is a cahracter limit?

Comment: yes, file names hould not be too long. I limited in the code above to 7 charcters. You can adjust it as you want. And with `gsub` I remove "sheet". try the new `file=` definition above!)

Comment: Where do I put arguments to ignore case etc?

Comment: `tolower()` makes that everything is lower case and since `"vivax"` is lower case, this in endeffect is the case ignoring.

Comment: how can I stop it creatingfiles that end in false? ie only make files with the word in them?

Comment: @Bohnston: see my modified answer.

Comment: it works. I don't think the `tolower` works as if i search any other term its case sensitive. Ie it wouldn't find Vivax

Comment: @Bohnston: I added `tolower` in `isWordInTibble` definition to make it case insensitive. The `tolower` in `write.csv` was to make `T` and `F` to lower case and not for the search.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Is it possible to make the search not case sensitive?

Comment: isn't it not case sensitive? if you compare two strings which were made lowercase by `tolower` - this is how case insensitivity is realized actually - you see that trick quite often. The tolower from before was not for the comparison but for the output - that is why it had no influence.